# how to select helper tags in events (handlebars/meteor)

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze

I have a reference to a helper called 'number' in my HTML:

```
Number of Entries: {{number}}
```

and that helper just counts how many entries are in my database

```
Template.general.helpers({
    number: function(){
        return collectionName.find().count()
    }
});
```

I'm trying to make an event so that when I click on the {{number}} element it will return that number to the console and I can't figure out how to get it to respond to the click at all, let alone respond with the number

```
Template.general.events({
    'click .number': function(){
        console.log('hi');
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe that you can use `{{#with number}}` to have the data context to change to the number and `{{.}}` inside the `with` clause to display it.

Comment: do you mean like this?

{{#with number}}{{.}}{{/with}}

because it's still not clickable after changing that...

Comment: What element is it in? I mean something like `{{#with number}}<span class="number">Number of Entries: {{.}}</span>{{/with}}`.

Comment: aha, perfect, that solved it! Giving it the span gives the event something solid to latch on to I suppose. Do you want to reply again with this and I will select it as the best answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to easily have the value available in the event handler and avoid unnecessary re-computations, it is possible to use a `{{#with}}` clause that sets the data context for its content, which is accessible via the dot (`{{.}}`) symbol.

```handlebars
{{#with number}}
  <span class="number">
    Number of Entries: {{.}}
  </span>
{{/with}}
```

This gives your handler both a `class` to hook to and the data context that will make the value easily accessible.

```js
Template.general.events({
  'click .number': function(e, tpl){
    console.log('the number is', this); //"this" is the data context
  }
});
```

Which will log the relevant count to the console.